# Integration of tail probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, expectation

Why does the following equality (from a book I'm reading) hold?
$$\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\big\{|X|^{2q}>x\big\}dx=\int_0^\infty 2qx^{2q-1}\mathbb{P}\{|X|>x\}dx$$

---

I know that $\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\big\{|X|^{2q}>x\big\}dx=\mathbb{E}[x^{2q}]$ (this is the starting point that led to this equation), and
I notice that $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x}x^{2q}=2qx^{2q-1}$.

I though it might be a specialization of some general case, something like  -
$$\int_0^\infty\mathbb{P}\Big\{f\big(g(x)\big)>x\Big\}dx=\int_0^\infty f'(x)\mathbb{P}\{g(x)>x\}dx$$
but the above doesn't hold in general.

It seems as if it should be trivial. I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y=x^{1/p}$, then $dx=py^{p-1}dy$. [Consequently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution), for $p>0$,
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\mathsf{P}\!\big(|X|^{p}>x\big)dx&=\int_0^\infty\mathsf{P}\big(|X|>x^{1/p}\big)dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty py^{p-1}\mathsf{P}\big(|X|>y\big)dy,
\end{align}
where the first equality holds because $x\mapsto x^{p}$ is increasing (on $[0,\infty)$).